# Weblogic : deploy war with prepared state not activate it

Tags: deployment, weblogic12c, wlst

I want to deploy war on Weblogic in state prepared not active
I am using Weblogic 12.2.1.2 and communicate with it using WLST, but web console can be an option.

How can I achieve this?